# Angular.js- Call scope function from outside the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, addeventlistener

I am new to angular.js and trying to figure out how to pass a json object from a even handler to scope function in a controller(or service instead?). I want the event listener to be outside of all controllers, etc. because I like the convention of just on event handler to listen for all events, rather than several event listeners for each event. How can I do this with Angular.js?

client code:

```
var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    console.log("connection was opened");
});
//Not using multi-listeners for each event.  
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
    event = Object.keys(result)[0];
    if (event == "cpuResult") {
        //call the function of cpuScope 
        //pass json into it
        } else if if (event == "networkResult") {
             //call the function of neworkScope
       and so on....
});

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
  }
},
```

false);

rough angular.js example:

```
   function cpuCtrl($scope) {

        // the last received msg
        $scope.msg = {};


        var updateElement = function (msg) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.msg = JSON.parse(msg.data)
            });
        }

     }
```

Comment: The worst answer will be to give you a plunker that works with what you've tried to do. Instead, I think you should just read about angular services and dependency injection, starting with services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and figure out the rest. Come back if you still have trouble :)

Comment: I think I see...I can make a service containing the event listener. If I inject that same service to each controller, will there be several event listeners? Or is it still just one eventlistener in the client?

Comment: Depends on your implementation. The best implementation I can think of is to have your service expose a "register" function that each controller can call and give it a callback as an argument. The service will keep an array of callbacks. The service will have one event listener, which when it triggers, will call all of the callbacks one by one. This can also be improved by including a "deregister" function you'll return when a controller no longer wants to get its callback called when the event triggers.